# How to select both sum value of all rows and values in some specific rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

I have a `record` table and its `comment` table, like:

```
| commentId | relatedRecordId | isRead |
|-----------+-----------------+--------|
| 1         | 1               | TRUE   |
| 2         | 1               | FALSE  |
| 3         | 1               | FALSE  |
```

Now I want to select `newCommentCount` and `allCommentCount` as a server response to the browser. Is there any way to select these two fields in one SQL?

---

I've tried this:

```sql
SELECT `isRead`, count(*) AS cnt FROM comment WHERE relatedRecordId=1 GROUP BY `isRead`
```

```
| isRead | cnt |
| FALSE  | 2   |
| TRUE   | 1   |
```

But, I have to use a special data structure to map it and sum the `cnt` fields in two rows to get `allCommentCount` by using an upper-layer programming language. I want to know if I could get the following format of data by SQL only and in one step:

```
| newCommentCount | allCommentCount |
|-----------------+-----------------|
| 2               | 3               |
```

I don't even know how to describe the question. So I got no any search result in Google and Stackoverflow. (Because of My poor English, maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT SUM(NOT isRead) AS newCommentCount, COUNT(*) AS allCommentCount
FROM comment
WHERE relatedRecordId = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

if I under stand you want show sum of newComments Count and all comments so  you can do it like

```
   SELECT  SUM ( CASE WHEN isRead=false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS newComment,
       Count(*) AS AllComments From comments where relatedRecord=1
```

also you can make store procedure for it.

Answer (score 1):

To place two result sets horizontally, you can as simple as use a subquery for an expression in the SELECT CLAUSE as long as the number of rows from the result sets match:

```
select (select count(*) from c_table where isread=false and relatedRecordId=1 ) as newCommentCount, 
count(*) as allCommentCount 
from c_table where relatedRecordId=1;
```

Comment: Does this solution search the table twice?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid so. The newCommentCount and allCommentCount will be calculated separately .  This is for the ease of use.  It's like using UNION, except  works horizontally .

Comment: Do this for simplicity when the data set is small and the query is fairly simple (like counting rows or other aggregate functions)